# How much would mass-production impact the cost of solid-fuel rockets?

Tags: rockets, construction, solid-fuel, logistics

Let's imagine that, for some arbitrary reason, solid-fuel rocket stages were needed and built en masse in factories, like planes or even like cars.

How much would it drive down the cost of an individual rocket stage?

What would be the impact if it had to be man-rated, like a Space Shuttle SRB? Would there be a significant difference between small sounding-rocket-like stages and big SRB( or ICBM)-like ones?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRAG_(rocket)

Comment: @Antzi Very interesting! Too bad it was killed by politics like the Babylon gun (for some reason, great powers don't like when rocket scientists go see that kind of regimes to develop their projects). Interorbital Systems seems to use the same approach, I wonder where it will get them.